# How to export UML diagram to image or PDF from PhpStorm?

Tags: php, uml, phpstorm

How can I export UML diagram to image or PDF from PhpStorm?

Tried many options. But it always get downloaded as an XML file. Would like to convert it to PDF or image file.

Edit: Using Phpstorm 2017.3 on MACOSX

Comment: Any tools you know to upload and view UML generated for phpstorm online ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Export to file` when viewing diagram -- there you can choose the exported format.

Screens from PhpStorm 2017.3

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry using MACOSX . Could not find save as image option

Comment: Do not have Mac -- cannot check it there. Show what you have got there (screenshots)

Comment: Can confirm on MacOS that file type select isn't available. If you explicitly specify ".png" in the filename, though, it'll export as such.